# Unable to create a new .Net Core console app

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, new-project

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 Professional version 15.4.0, and I'm trying to create a new .Net Core console application, but I'm getting this message:

```
    Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
```

During the installation process, I've checked the following options:

[image: Selected packages]
After facing the problem, I ran the installer again, chose "Modify installed components",  and marked ".NET Core 1.0 - 1.1 development tools for Web" and ".NET Core runtime" for installation with no success. After that, I downloaded .Net Core SDK from Microsoft website, and now, I get this message with no further information.
[image: Project creation failed]
 Any solutions?

Comment: The current .NET Core version is 2.2. The current long-term-support version is 2.1. 1.0 and 1.1 are either out of long-term support already or getting out of support very soon.

Comment: The latest Visual Studio upgrade is 15.9.7. You should upgrade to the current versions before trying to work with .NET Core.

Comment: Try running `dotnet --version` and `dotnet --list-sdks` from a command line. Which versions do you see? You should be able to create a new console project with `dotnet new console`

Comment: Depending on the version of .NET Core, there are different prerequisites:  
e.g. .NET Core 1.x apps, Visual Studio 2017 version 15.0 or higher,  
.NET Core 2.1 apps, Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 or higher,  
.NET Core 2.2 apps, Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 or higher.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites

Comment: .net version: 2.2.104, sdks:
1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) suggested, I upgraded my Visual Studio, and now it's working like charm! Thanks again  [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos).